# network issues in dockerfile while accessing database

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pip

I have an small python backend and a mariaDB. Deperated in Docker Services.

The docker-compse looks like this:

```
version: '3.5'

networks:
  web:
    name: web
    external: true
  wsm:
    name: wsm
    internal: true
volumes:
  wsm-partsfinder-db:
    name: wsm-partsfinder-db

services:
  wsmbackend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    container_name: wsm-file-parts-backend
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - wsmdb
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    networks:
      - web
      - wsm
  wsmdb:
    container_name: wsmdb
    image: mariadb:10.7.1
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mariadb_native_password
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MARIADB_USER: wsm
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: password
      MARIADB_DATABASE: wsm_parts
    volumes:
      - wsm-partsfinder-db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - wsm
    ports:
      - "4485:3306"
```

The Dockerfile which is called for wsmbackend service looks like this:

```
FROM python

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

COPY . /wsm
WORKDIR /wsm

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN yoyo apply --database mysql://wsm:password@wsmdb:4485/wsm_parts ./migrations

EXPOSE 8888
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "python main.py"]
```

I got an error in yoyo apply ...

[image]

What is the issue in this case?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to run queries on the database in your build stage, because your database container not is started at that current point.

The `RUN` statement is only executed in the build stage. You need to move it to the `CMD` (entrypoint), so it's executed when the container and the database is started.

Comment: thanks. that looks much better. the docker is starting with no error. But, the command is not executed. Any idea why?

Comment: Not really. Have you pulled the logs for the container?

Comment: yes no error and no execution logs for this statement `CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "yoyo apply --database mysql://wsm:password@wsmdb/wsm_parts ./migrations"]`

Comment: A Docker container only runs one `CMD`.  This is where the `ENTRYPOINT` wrapper script concept comes in, as a place to let you run setup commands like this before running the `CMD` with `exec "$@"`.